# Is there more specific/deep options for changing print area for excel file with aspire XLS library?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, wpf, spire.xls

I'm generating a file, but printing area is not that accurately stands. How can i move that dotted line to the next row? Is there any actually existing methods?
[dotted line should be in straight line's place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6v3R.png)

PS: default excel object library isn't that comfortable for me, and it doesn't open generated file correctly.

Tried:
worksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:M39"; - actually moves **straight** line

string s = worksheet.Range[1, 1, 39,12].RangeAddressLocal;
worksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = s; - does nothing with dotted line

Answer (score 0):

The dashed lines are page breaks automatically added by Excel, while the solid lines are page breaks that you have added manually. Automatic page breaks are determined by Excel based on factors such as the page size, margins, and content. Unlike manual page breaks, automatic page breaks cannot be directly moved to another location.

See this link for more information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-move-or-delete-page-breaks-in-a-worksheet-ad3dc726-beec-4a4c-861f-ed640612bdc2